# How can I upload images from gallery to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**PostViewController**

I'm working on a **social app**. In which I want to upload photos from gallery to my **TableViewCell** by **UploadButton**. By **programmatically** I created some posts, as shown in **MainScreenViewController**, like facebook or instagram. But now I want to add a photo by picking up from gallery and upload to the VC.

This is my **PostViewController** in which I'm getting a photo from library and now I want to post it on **MainScreenViewController's [ViewControllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jUmQ.png)TableView**.

Kindly help at this point

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class PostViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var ref = DatabaseReference.init()

    @IBOutlet weak var txtText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnUpload: UIButton!
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnUpload.designButton(borderWidth: 0, borderColor: UIColor.clear)
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PostViewController.openGallery(tapGesture:)))
        myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
    }
    
    func saveFIRData() {
        self.uploadImage(self.myImageView.image!) { url in
            self.saveImage(name: self.txtText.text!, profileURL: url!) { success in
                if success != nil {
                    print("Good")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc func openGallery(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.setUpImagePicker()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnSaveClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.saveFIRData()
    }
}

extension PostViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func setUpImagePicker() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.isEditing = true
            
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        myImageView.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}

extension PostViewController {
    func uploadImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())) {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
        let imgData = myImageView.image?.pngData()
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/png"
        storageRef.putData(imgData!, metadata: metaData) { (metdata, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Success")
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    completion(url!)
                })
            } else {
                print("error in save image")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveImage(name: String, profileURL: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())) {
        let dict = ["name": "Omer", "text": txtText.text!, "profileURL": profileURL.absoluteString] as [String: Any]
        self.ref.child("chat").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
    }
}
```

**MainScreenViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class MainScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var cardTableView: UITableView!
    
    let pictures: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "1")!, UIImage(named: "2")!, UIImage(named: "3")!]
    let images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "aa")!, UIImage(named: "ab")!, UIImage(named: "ac")!]
    let titles: [String] = ["Che Guevara", "BatMan", "Information Technology"]
    let descriptions: [String] = ["Ernesto Che Guevara was an Argentine Marxist revolutionary, guerrilla leader.", "Batman ventures into Gotham City's underworld.", "Information technology is defined as a broad term that includes the development."]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cardTableView.delegate = self
        cardTableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 400
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
        cell.configure(picture: pictures[indexPath.row], img: images[indexPath.row], title: titles[indexPath.row], description: descriptions[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

**CardCell**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class CardCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pictureView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLike: UIButton!
    
    // set up the cell
    func configure(picture: UIImage, img: UIImage, title: String, description: String) {
        pictureView.image = picture
        profileImage.image = img
        titleLabel.text = title
        descriptionLabel.text = description
        
        cardView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnLike_Click(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if btnLike.tag == 0 {
            btnLike.setImage(UIImage(named: "h1"), for: .normal)
            btnLike.tag = 1
        } else {
            btnLike.setImage(UIImage(named: "h4"), for: .normal)
            btnLike.tag = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use closure to pass data back to MainVC which I found it lot easier

**Create a closure in PostViewController** :

```
var uploadedImage : ((UIImage)->Void)?
```

**Assign the uploadedImage property before the picker is dismissed**

```
uploadedImage(myUplodedImage)?
```

**Use the property of the closure when you initiate it on MainViewController**

```
let vc = PostViewController(nibName : "something", bundle : nil)
vc.uploadedImage = {
// Add some action here when the PostViewController dismiss
}
navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated : true)
```

**Additional references** :

[Passing Data Between View Controllers](https://www.appypie.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to#Closure)